# Python - how do i add the long command to the subprocess, when i am applything in one line the whole command is not working

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

How do i add this full `export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /home/src/upload.py %s %s &` command to the subprocess?

```
# valid command
u ="""export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /home/src/upload.py %s %s &""" % (s[1], s[2])
d ="""export DISPLAY=:0.0 && python /home/src/download.py %s %s &""" % (s[1], s[2])

# seems to work like this but need to add the u and d on this
subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/upload.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/download.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add the `DISPLAY` variable to the environment variables; the arguments are extre elements of the argument list:

```
import os

env = os.environ.copy()
env['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/upload.py"] + s[1:3], 
                      env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/download.py"] + s[1:3], 
                      env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What your commands basically do is setting an environment variable and then invoking a python script with parameters. You can achieve this by modifying your code to read:

```py
import os
import subprocess

new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'

subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/upload.py", s[1], s[2]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=new_env)
subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/src/download.py", s[1], s[2]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=new_env)
```